# Structure padding in C

Tags: c, optimization, structure

I've read this about structure padding in C:
http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/543879-what-structure-padding
and wrote this code after the article, what should print out size of 'struct pad' like 16 byte and the size of 'struct pad2' should be 12. -as I think.
I compiled this code with gcc, with different levels of optimization, even the sizeof() operator gives me both of them 16 byte. 
Why is it?

This information is necessary for me because of PS3 machines, where the byte boundaries and exploitation of the full dma transfer is important:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct pad
{
    char  c1;  // 1 byte
    short s1;  // 2 byte
    short s2;  // 2 byte
    char  c2;  // 1 byte
    long  l1;  // 4 byte
    char  c3;  // 1 byte
};

struct pad2
{
    long  l1;
    short s1;
    short s2;
    char  c1;
    char  c2;
    char  c3;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct pad P1;
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(P1));

    struct pad P2;
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(P2));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: The article is broadly wrong, because it tries to define specific rules for alignment without specifying the architecture. All alignment rules are architecture-specific; furthermore, compilers typically have switches to further control alignment (the architecture may define the minimum required one, but you can always align on double/triple/... boundaries).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two tricks that can be used to owercome this problem

1. Using directive `#pragma pack(push, 1)` and then `#pragma pack(pop)`.

   Example:

   ```
   #pragma pack(push, 1)

   struct tight{
      short element_1;
      int *element_2;
   };
   #pragma pack(pop)

   struct not_tight{
      short element_1;
      int *element_2;
   };
   ```
2. To check if the sizes of two structs are same during compilation use this trick

   ```
    char voidstr[(sizeof(struct1)==sizeof(struct2)) - 1]; //it will return error at compile time if this fail
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Your structures each include a `long`, which your platform apparently requires to be on a four-byte boundary.  The structure must be at least as aligned as its most aligned member, so it has to be 4-byte aligned, and a structure's size has to be a multiple of its alignment in case it goes into an array.

Extra padding is required to make the `long` aligned, and so the smallest multiple of 4 is 16.

Two pieces of advice:

- You can compute the offset of a field `l1` by

  ```
   printf("Offset of field %s is %d\n", "l1", offsetof(struct pad, l1);
  ```

  To get the `offsetof` macro you will need to `#include <stddef.h>` (thanks caf!).
- If you want to pack data as densely as possible, use `unsigned char[4]` instead of `long` and `unsigned char[2]` instead of `short`, and do the arithmetic to convert.

---

**EDIT**:: The `sizeof(struct pad2)` *is* 12.  Your code has a bug; structure `P2` is declared of type `struct pad`.  Try this:

```
#define xx(T) printf("sizeof(" #T ") == %d\n", sizeof(T))
  xx(struct pad);
  xx(struct pad2);
```

P.S. I should definitely stop trying to answer SO questions after midnight.

Comment: Or you could use offsetof(struct pad, l1) :)

Comment: Oh, and 12 is a multiple of 4 too, so that doesn't actually explain it.

Answer (score 1):

On PS3, don't guess.  Use `__attribute__((aligned (16)))`, or similar.   Not only does it guarantee that the start of the structure will be aligned on a proper boundary (if global or static), it also pads the structure to a multiple of your specified alignment.

Comment: I thinks there may be some problem with the boundaries, when somebody want to transfer data between PPE and SPE below 16 byte. This guarantee may cause hazard between addresses. -but exactly I don't know. What do you think?

Comment: As long as things are 16 byte aligned on both ends it will still work, but you get better speed if you can 128 byte align both sides.  I'm not sure exactly why, it's just a rule of thumb to 128 byte align buffers that receive DMA for us.

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't showing what you think it is, because both P1 and P2 are defined as instances of struct pad.  struct pad2 isn't ever used.

If I change the definition of P2 so that it is struct pad2, gcc does indeed decide to make it size 12.

Comment: Congratulations, you're the first one to get this right - God, it took a while for someone to do that! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
struct pad P1;
printf("%d\n", sizeof(P1));

struct pad P2;
printf("%d\n", sizeof(P2));
```

P1 and P2 have the same type "struct pad" maybe you want to use "struct pad2" for P2.

Comment: Good spotting of the obvious (once spotted)!

Answer (score 1):

All CPU expect that the built in data types like (int, float,char,double) are stored in the memory at their natural boundary, at address of their length.So structure padding is done to faster access of data from memory.
For example,
If int is declared, it should occurs in the memory at an address multiple of 4, as

size of the int is 4 byte.

Similarly for double, it resides in memory at multiple of 8.

If memory is properly aligned, CPU can run faster and work efficiently.

For the following examples, let us assume:

Sizeof(int)=4 byte

Sizeof(float)=4 byte

Sizeof(char)=1 byte

Find details on [BoundsCheck](http://www.boundscheck.com/knowledge-base/c-cpp/structure-padding-in-c/360/)